# Probability of selecting a certain card

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is my question:
Suppose you are playing black jack, you are dealt a (5) and a (6), while the dealer was dealt a (k) and a (2). What is the probability of yourself selecting a (10, K, Q, or J) in order to get to 21.

I don't know too much about combinatorics or Probability theory but I would assume that since there are 52 cards in total and 4 are already out on the table we have -

(4/52) or (1/13) is the new base probability you have to work with. You have 15 (10, K, Q, or J) you can get so would it be, (1/13)*(15/52)?

*(We are assuming it is just you and the dealer and there is only one deck of cards).*

Please go easy on me since I have very little experience in this sort of thing.

Thank you!

Comment: If you already took 4 cards, doesn't the new probabilty become ${{4\over{52-4}}={4\over48}={1\over12}}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $15$ cards left which will work, and there are $48$ cards to choose from, so the answer is simply $\frac{15}{48}=\frac5{16}$.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was easier than I was making it.